# PHP fopen Permission Denied - Windows Server remotely

Tags: php, iis, permissions, fopen

I have a PHP project in Windows Server 2012 & Xampp 1.8.2. I've tried to read some remote HTML content from another Windows Server 2008 with IIS:

```
$handle = fopen("\\\\SERVER001\\Webdocs\\page\\index.html", 'r');
```

...but I have this message:

> Warning: fopen(\SERVER001\Webdocs\page\index.html): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ...

But if I'm accessing with the file protocol, works fine:

> file://///SERVER001/Webdocs/page/index.html

I've added the IP server in the `ipv4 address and domain restrictions` option of IIS, I've gotten the same result.

I think is problem of Windows Server 2012 (or apache) because I've tested the same project (localhost) in my PC Windows 7, the same xampp 1.8.2., I've added my IP in the `ipv4 address and domain restrictions` in the 2008 Server and `fopen()` works without problems and extra configurations. The only difference from the server and my PC is the OS.

What another thing I do to have permission on this server?

**Permissions:**

[image: Permissions:]

Comment: What are the file permissions?

Comment: Total control ... this is relevant? because my PC could accessed without problems!

Comment: More along the lines of 0777? 0644?

Comment: like the image above

Comment: Have you turned the firewall off for both machines? Do you have any `open_basedir` restrictions?

Comment: Firewall in windows 2012 is Off (as my PC), open_basedir doesn't have nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the problem:

> apache service in netstat running like a local user

The difference between my PC and Windows Server is my Xampp's Control doesn't have the apache service installed. When this is installed, the Apache service running like a local user (not like a user in the active directory domain).

So is necessary asign a domain user  in:

> Services > Apache > Properties > Log On tab > This account

Restart Apache and works!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have the webserver setup as local. Also check file permissions